# programmatically add css class to ListItem

Tags: asp.net, webforms, listitem

I need to produce with asp.net controls this structure, but ListItem doesn't allow add properties and classes.

What is the best way to do it?

```
<ul>
 <li class="1">SomeText</li>
 <li class="2">SomeText2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can pass-through class attribute:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem class="1">SomeText</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem class="2">SomeText2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

. . .

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListItem listItem = new ListItem("Test 3");
   listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "3");
   BulletedList1.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can still add custom attributes:

```
// assuming li is your WebControl or HtmlControl:
li.Attributes.Add("class", "1");
```

Comment: How can he specify different classes for each list item with this code?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me, but using dropdownlist and VB

```
    Dim ListItem As ListItem = New ListItem("All folders", 0)
    ListItem.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red;")
    DropDownListFolders.Items.Add(ListItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dropdown in listview -- if you want to give popup window on selecting item when dropdown textsize is fixed:

```
protected void lstViewVehicle_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{        
    try
    {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.InsertItem)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlDescription");
        if (ddl != null)
        {
            string description = exp_Type_Vehicle;
            clsBER objclsBER = new clsBER();
            DataSet ds = objclsBER.FillDropdown(description);

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                ListItem lstitem = new ListItem(dr["expense_description"].ToString(), dr["eid"].ToString());
                lstitem.Attributes.Add("title", dr["expense_description"].ToString());
                //lstitem.Attributes.Add("style", "color:blue");
                ddl.Items.Add(lstitem);
            }
            ddl.DataBind();
        }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        (new csComman()).dealWithEx(ex, Session);
        Response.Redirect("ErrorPage/ErrorPage.aspx", false);
    }   
}
```