# Adding class to listitem from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to add class to my pagination from cs file. But the css is not been applied to it.

```
if (pageCount > 0)
    {
        ListItem lp = new ListItem("Previous", "1", currentPage > 1);
        lp.Attributes.Add("class","pages previous");
        pages.Add(lp);
        //pages.Add(new ListItem("First", "1", currentPage > 1));
        for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
        {
           // pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != currentPage));
            ListItem li = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != currentPage);
            li.Attributes.Add("class", "pages");


            pages.Add(li);
        }
        ListItem ll = new ListItem("Next", pageCount.ToString(), currentPage < pageCount);
        ll.Attributes.Add("class", "pages next");
        pages.Add(ll);
        //pages.Add(new ListItem("Last", pageCount.ToString(), currentPage < pageCount));
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: on which event you written this code??

Comment: I want to add pagination so i write this code in a function which is called at page load and when the user clicks on the page link

Comment: try to put this code on prerender event..

Comment: I tried that but no luck

Comment: Please any ideas or solution. It is urgent :(

Answer (score 0):

See [programmatically add css class to ListItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030844/programmatically-add-css-class-to-listitem)

If CSS is not being applied, then it might be more useful to post the HTML that is generated, and the CSS rules that you are hoping to be applied.