# C# dropdown list item color doesn't display when selected

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

[image]

This is a ASP .NET application with C# in the code behind. I am able to add background color to dropdown list items but when I make a selection, the color doesn't persist in Chrome or IE 11. Works fine in IE 9.

**What have I done so far (taking hints from another question on SO):**

Added `onchange="SelectedItemCLR(this);"` to my DropDownList. But not sure what to do now to persist the color.

The SelectedItemCLR function (from another question in SO) looks like this:

```
/* Persist the color of the selected item */
function SelectedItemCLR(source) 
{
    if (source.options[source.selectedIndex].value == "Yellow") {
        // ??? 
    }
    else if (source.options[source.selectedIndex].value == "Red") {
    }
    else if (source.options[source.selectedIndex].value == "Green") {
    }
}
```

Is this more of a browser issue that I have to live with? :(

**Edit:**
In the server side C# code, I have this code to color the items.

```
foreach (ListItem item in ddlOverallStatus.Items)
{
    if (item.Value == "Red")
    {
        item.Attributes.Add("style", "padding:2px;background-color:#B22222;color:#fff");
    }
    else if (item.Value == "Yellow")
    {
        item.Attributes.Add("style", "padding:2px;background-color:yellow;color:#000");
    }
    else if (item.Value == "Green")
    {
        item.Attributes.Add("style", "padding:2px;background-color:green;color:#fff");
    }
}
```

**Works fine in IE 9**

[image]

**Edit - Got it working with Chrome.**

1. Add `onchange="SelectedItemCLR(this);` to your asp:DropDownList.
2. Function SelectedItemCLR looks like:

```js
function SelectedItemCLR(source) 
{
 if (source.options[source.selectedIndex].value == "Yellow") {
  $('#<%=  ddlOverallStatus.ClientID %>').addClass("YellowDropdownListItem");
 }
 else if (source.options[source.selectedIndex].value == "Red") {
 }
 else if (source.options[source.selectedIndex].value == "Green") {
 }
 else {
 }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to have it persist between? Browser restarts? Page changes? Simply past it being clicked?

Comment: Are you asking what to write in javascript to change the background of the combobox' to the selected color?
If so, I would expect you'd need to modify `source`'s style (background-color).

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear. Just when the user makes a selection, the background color is lost.

Comment: I would suggest making a css class for your drop down list and do the coloring there. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color to get you started.

Comment: What are you doing to make it lose/modify the color? From what you've posted, nothing should be changing it yet.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein All I am doing here is making a selection once the page loads and the background color is lost.

Comment: @JohnPaul Please see my edit. Albeit, not very neat, but I am effectively applying CSS to color the list items. When the user selects one (without any post back), for some reason, the background-color is lost.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you shouldn't be applying the css through code. You should implement it in a stylesheet and then have the drop down list inherit that class. That's what stylesheets are for.

Comment: a) I am using <asp:ListItem> inside the <asp:DropDownList> for which you cannot add CSSClass attribute, b) You cannot add a CSS class using item.Attributes.Add ... the example in the link above shows a html select-option tag. Won't work in this case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030844/programmatically-add-css-class-to-listitem. Also just add the attribute class="yourClassName"

Comment: Hi  John ... I had this code following your last comment: if (item.Value == "Red")
                {
                    
                    item.Attributes.Add("class", "RedDropdownListItem");

                }  ... didn't work.

Comment: @JohnPaul .. thanks for your help though. I think it's one of those ASP inconsistencies.

Comment: @JohnPaul You were right though. You can just add a class attribute to the <asp:ListItem> .... but the problem still remains. When I select, the background color disappears. I tried this ... <asp:ListItem Class="RedDropdownListItem" Text="Red" Value="Red" Selected="false"></asp:ListItem>

Comment: Hmm...Are you able to change the background color in chrome using the developer tools? I did some research and I think it has something to do with Chrome and webkit not sure exactly what the issue is though.

Comment: I can change the background-color of the dropdown list using developer tools (inspect element). So I am going to try to write some JavaScript to do this on the selection changed event. Will post my update soon.

Comment: Ok I'm trying tod o the same in jsfidddle. I'll post an answer if I can figure it out.

Comment: Got it to work please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it to work. Check out my working jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/fbou1srd/.

HTML

```
<select id="dropDown" onchange="changeColor();">
    <option val="Red">Red</option>
    <option val="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option val="Green">Green</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
select option[val="Red"] {
    background-color: red;
}

select option[val="Yellow"] {
    background-color: yellow;
}

select option[val="Green"] {
    background-color: green;
}
```

JS

```
function changeColor() {
    var select = $("#dropDown");
    if(select.val() === "Red") {
        select.css("background-color", "Red");
    }
    else if(select.val() === "Yellow") {
        select.css("background-color", "Yellow");
    }
    else if(select.val() === "Green") {
        select.css("background-color", "Green");
    }
}
```

Comment: However, if you're in a C#, ASP .NET world, you will need slight modification to John's code above. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to style the DropDownList  itself, not just each Item .

You can do this with the OnSelectedIndexChanged event like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOverallStatus" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOverallStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in code behind:

```
protected void ddlOverallStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ddlOverallStatus.SelectedValue == "Red")
        {
            ddlOverallStatus.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#B22222;color:#fff");
        }
        else if (ddlOverallStatus.SelectedValue == "Yellow")
        {
            ddlOverallStatus.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:yellow;color:#000");
        }
        else if (ddlOverallStatus.SelectedValue == "Green")
        {
            ddlOverallStatus.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:green;color:#fff");
        }
    }
```

Another option would be to do it Client side with Javascript.

Comment: This is going to send a HTTP request every time the user changes a drop-down selection :(